# running different nodes from a shell script

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have different nodes from different packages and I want to run it from a single shell script. The description is given below:

I have 3 different packages and each package contains 3 different nodes

```
(sample directory structure)
    package_name1
    |— src
        |— node1_node.cpp
    |— CMakeLists.txt
    |— package.xml
    
    package_name2
    |— src
        |— node2_node.cpp
    |— CMakeLists.txt
    |— package.xml
    
    package_name3
    |— src
        |— node3_node.cpp
    |— CMakeLists.txt
    |— package.xml
```

Each package has 1 executable. Every time I have to go to each executable path and execute. Instead of that I want to write a single script which will run the 3 different executable from 3 packages.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried by running the script:

```
cd path_to_package_name1/devel/lib/package_name1
./node1_node
cd path_to_package_name2/devel/lib/package_name2
./node2_node
cd path_to_package_name3/devel/lib/package_name3
./node3_node
```

But it is executing only the first node.How can I execute the 3 nodes together?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274183/running-different-nodes-from-a-shell-script/) by [rosusernli](https://answers.ros.org/users/31974/rosusernli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless you have a specific reason to use them, I would stay away from using shell scripts.

To start individual nodes, use `rosrun`: `rosrun pkg_name node_name`.

To start entire applications, use `roslaunch`: `roslaunch pkg_name some_file.launch`.

See #q268337 for an older question about this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
And if you haven't yet, also take a look at the [wiki/Using rqt_console and roslaunch - Using roslaunch](http://mirror-eu.wiki.ros.org/ROS(2f)Tutorials(2f)UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch.html#Using_roslaunch) tutorial. That should have covered this.

Have you done the basic tutorials?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
And I'm linking to the `eu` mirror of the wiki as it appears to be down right now.

**Comment by [rosusernli](https://answers.ros.org/users/31974/rosusernli/) on 2017-10-27**:
I usually run the executable directly rather than using rosrun. But when I used rosrun the following error occured:
'package not found'

I sourced the setup.bash file of the workspace and appended the src path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.But the error remained the same.
Any suggestions on this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
I would really recommend you start using `rosrun` for this.

> appended the src path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

don't do that. Ever.

Please *edit* your question with the complete error message that you get, and with the output of `ls -al /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
Also: I only mentioned `rosrun` as you were starting binaries directly, which is not really 'the ROS way'.

Your question is/was about starting multiple nodes properly, which is really what `roslaunch` was created for.

**Comment by [rosusernli](https://answers.ros.org/users/31974/rosusernli/) on 2017-10-27**:
Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I found out why it was giving  'package not found' . There was a space in my file path. Really sorry to bother you for this.

I am now able to use roslaunch and run the applications. Thanks for suggesting the ros way of running it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
You're welcome. No need to apologise.